# How do you add blank space in mail merge?

Tags: email, merge, space

Can anyone tell me how to add blank spaces in mail merge 2007? I'm printing labels for file folders that contain the month and year. The problem I would like to have a blank space between the month & year. i'm making a list of months & years in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As the dates are in Excel, the display format there will copied into the mail merge field(s)
*[Assumed, Expected, not checked]*.

**How to format dates in Excel / Libre Office:**

Select the cells that contain the dates, set display format for them by:

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  ( = "press" CTRL+1)

In the dialog that opens:
Find "User defined" (in Libre Office) or "Custom" (in Excel) and click on it.

Now you should see a "Format code" field (Libre Office) or a corresponding field in Excel *(I'm writing this from memory, don't remember the actual text)*

Type `YYYY  MM` in the format code field (English locale) or e.g. `ÅÅÅÅ MM` (Excel, Swedish locale, "År" <=> "Year") to have a four digit year appear with a two digit month after it.
Any number of spaces you add between those will be copied when the cell content is shown. You may also add some text or characters, e.g. `-YY- -MM-` will show `-20- -01-` for 2020-01-01.

Click `OK` to set the changes.

To have the month displayed as text, use MMM or MMMM for e.g. "Jan" or "January".

The available codes are described in the Number and Dates format codes defined for the "TEXT()" function in your help file, or on the internet. e.g. [TEXT()-function](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3147132), and the [Number formats](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/01/05020301.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=UNIX) linked from there.